# How to generate the in-game world map UI for a large world?

Tags: textures, gui, maps

I would like to generate a map of the game world (i.e. a world map for a full screen UI). I am not an artist so would like to automate the process. For small levels I was able to do this by capturing the scene with an orthographic camera offline into a texture. Now that my world is bigger (~100km x 100km) I worry about how big the texture will need to be for this to work. What are some common approaches for solving this?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the approach to rendering something "too large" in any sense is to split it into several overlapping small parts, render each part separately and then compose the individual render results, by hand or automatically.